# Only show valued data on xAxis in amcharts in a date range

Tags: range, amcharts, axis-labels

I am trying to force on Xaxis labels for range, only the dates 1/10 or 1 Oct , for each point where i have datas , i mean i want to exclude the automated oct nov dec jan from the xaxis and place only the ones that have data , i dont mind if it does not follow a perfect pattern , i just want the days/month to appear just down the points where i have values to show.

[image]

I leave here the actual code adapted to this snippet ... where it shows months instead of day/month but i believe its due to automatic rendering of x-axis legend that is what i am trying to prevent....for my customised days with data only x-axis range labels....

```js
 am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
          
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
        var chart = am4core.create("modalContensfromAjax", am4charts.XYChart);
// Create axes
//         var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
//
            /**
             * Use separate DateFormatter for X axis, so we can set different format
             * (this presumes that X axis of type DateAxis was already created)
             */
                // Create axes
        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.endLocation  = 3.5;
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "top";
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 272;
            dateAxis.dataFields.category = 'sales';
            dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
            dateAxis.fontSize = 14;
      
            // // Create series

        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            valueAxis.title.text = "# Incidents ";
        var incomingdata ='{"SKATES":[{"date":"2019-10-10","SKATES":1},{"date":"2019-12-16","SKATES":2},{"date":"2020-1-3","SKATES":3},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-6","SKATES":4},{"date":"2020-1-7","SKATES":5},{"date":"2020-1-9","SKATES":6},{"date":"2020-1-13","SKATES":8},{"date":"2020-1-15","SKATES":9},{"date":"2020-1-23","SKATES":11},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-27","SKATES":12},{"date":"2020-1-28","SKATES":13},{"date":"2020-1-29","SKATES":23}],\n' +
            '"SHIPS":[{"date":"2019-11-24","SHIPS":1},{"date":"2019-12-13","SHIPS":2},{"date":"2020-1-6","SHIPS":3},{"date":"2020-1-21","SHIPS":4},{"date":"2020-1-22","SHIPS":6},{"date":"2020-1-24","SHIPS":7},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-29","SHIPS":11}],"CARS":[{"date":"2019-11-26","CARS":1},{"date":"2019-12-23","CARS":2},{"date":"2020-1-13","CARS":3}],\n' +
            '"MOTORCICLES":[{"date":"2019-12-19","MOTORCICLES":1},{"date":"2020-1-23","MOTORCICLES":2},{"date":"2020-1-28","MOTORCICLES":3},{"date":"2020-1-29","MOTORCICLES":6}],\n' +
            '"BICICLES":[{"date":"2020-1-24","BICICLES":1}]}';
        var aResult = $.parseJSON(incomingdata);
            $.each(aResult, function(key, value) {
                createSeries( key, "Series #" + key,value)
            });

     function createSeries(s, name,seriesVal) {

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
         var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
         valueLabel.label.text = "{valueY}";
         valueLabel.label.fontSize = 20;
         valueLabel.label.y = -13.5;
                bullet.fill = am4core.color("#3f5163");
                bullet.fillOpacity = 1;
                bullet.strokeWidth = 2;
                bullet.circle.radius = 4;

                series.dataFields.valueY = s;
                series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
                series.dataFields.dateX.showTooltipOn = "always";
series.dataFields.dateX.dateFormatter = new am4core.DateFormatter();
                series.dataFields.dateX.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";




         // Create series
                series.name = name;

        var segment = series.segments.template;
                segment.interactionsEnabled = true;

        var hoverState = segment.states.create("hover");
                hoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 6;

        var dimmed = segment.states.create("dimmed");
                dimmed.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#dadada");

                segment.events.on("over", function(event) {
                    processOver(event.target.parent.parent.parent);
                });

                segment.events.on("out", function(event) {
                    processOut(event.target.parent.parent.parent);
                });
                series.data = eval(seriesVal);
                return series;
            }
            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
            chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
            chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
            chart.legend.position = "right";
            chart.legend.scrollable = true;
            chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("over", function(event) {
                processOver(event.target.dataItem.dataContext);
            })

            chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("out", function(event) {
                processOut(event.target.dataItem.dataContext);
            })

            

            function processOver(hoveredSeries) {
                hoveredSeries.toFront();

                hoveredSeries.segments.each(function(segment) {
                    segment.setState("hover");
                })

                chart.series.each(function(series) {
                    if (series != hoveredSeries) {
                        series.segments.each(function(segment) {
                            segment.setState("dimmed");
                        })
                        series.bulletsContainer.setState("dimmed");
                    }
                });
            }

            function processOut(hoveredSeries) {
                chart.series.each(function(series) {
                    series.segments.each(function(segment) {
                        segment.setState("default");
                    })
                    series.bulletsContainer.setState("default");
                });
            }

        }); // end am4core.ready()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="modalContensfromAjax">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateAxis` has a property for that: [`skipEmptyPeriods`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Removing_empty_time_units).

```
dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;
```

It will remove days without data.

```js
 am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
          
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
        var chart = am4core.create("modalContensfromAjax", am4charts.XYChart);
// Create axes
//         var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
//
            /**
             * Use separate DateFormatter for X axis, so we can set different format
             * (this presumes that X axis of type DateAxis was already created)
             */
                // Create axes
        var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
            dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.endLocation  = 3.5;
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.horizontalCenter = "right";
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.verticalCenter = "top";
            dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.rotation = 272;
            dateAxis.dataFields.category = 'sales';
            dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
            dateAxis.fontSize = 14;
            dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;
      
            // // Create series

        var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
            valueAxis.title.text = "# Incidents ";
        var incomingdata ='{"SKATES":[{"date":"2019-10-10","SKATES":1},{"date":"2019-12-16","SKATES":2},{"date":"2020-1-3","SKATES":3},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-6","SKATES":4},{"date":"2020-1-7","SKATES":5},{"date":"2020-1-9","SKATES":6},{"date":"2020-1-13","SKATES":8},{"date":"2020-1-15","SKATES":9},{"date":"2020-1-23","SKATES":11},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-27","SKATES":12},{"date":"2020-1-28","SKATES":13},{"date":"2020-1-29","SKATES":23}],\n' +
            '"SHIPS":[{"date":"2019-11-24","SHIPS":1},{"date":"2019-12-13","SHIPS":2},{"date":"2020-1-6","SHIPS":3},{"date":"2020-1-21","SHIPS":4},{"date":"2020-1-22","SHIPS":6},{"date":"2020-1-24","SHIPS":7},\n' +
            '{"date":"2020-1-29","SHIPS":11}],"CARS":[{"date":"2019-11-26","CARS":1},{"date":"2019-12-23","CARS":2},{"date":"2020-1-13","CARS":3}],\n' +
            '"MOTORCICLES":[{"date":"2019-12-19","MOTORCICLES":1},{"date":"2020-1-23","MOTORCICLES":2},{"date":"2020-1-28","MOTORCICLES":3},{"date":"2020-1-29","MOTORCICLES":6}],\n' +
            '"BICICLES":[{"date":"2020-1-24","BICICLES":1}]}';
        var aResult = $.parseJSON(incomingdata);
            $.each(aResult, function(key, value) {
                createSeries( key, "Series #" + key,value)
            });

     function createSeries(s, name,seriesVal) {

        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
         var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
         valueLabel.label.text = "{valueY}";
         valueLabel.label.fontSize = 20;
         valueLabel.label.y = -13.5;
                bullet.fill = am4core.color("#3f5163");
                bullet.fillOpacity = 1;
                bullet.strokeWidth = 2;
                bullet.circle.radius = 4;

                series.dataFields.valueY = s;
                series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
                series.dataFields.dateX.showTooltipOn = "always";
series.dataFields.dateX.dateFormatter = new am4core.DateFormatter();
                series.dataFields.dateX.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";




         // Create series
                series.name = name;

        var segment = series.segments.template;
                segment.interactionsEnabled = true;

        var hoverState = segment.states.create("hover");
                hoverState.properties.strokeWidth = 6;

        var dimmed = segment.states.create("dimmed");
                dimmed.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#dadada");

                segment.events.on("over", function(event) {
                    processOver(event.target.parent.parent.parent);
                });

                segment.events.on("out", function(event) {
                    processOut(event.target.parent.parent.parent);
                });
                series.data = eval(seriesVal);
                return series;
            }
            chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
            chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
            chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
            chart.legend.position = "right";
            chart.legend.scrollable = true;
            chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("over", function(event) {
                processOver(event.target.dataItem.dataContext);
            })

            chart.legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("out", function(event) {
                processOut(event.target.dataItem.dataContext);
            })

            

            function processOver(hoveredSeries) {
                hoveredSeries.toFront();

                hoveredSeries.segments.each(function(segment) {
                    segment.setState("hover");
                })

                chart.series.each(function(series) {
                    if (series != hoveredSeries) {
                        series.segments.each(function(segment) {
                            segment.setState("dimmed");
                        })
                        series.bulletsContainer.setState("dimmed");
                    }
                });
            }

            function processOut(hoveredSeries) {
                chart.series.each(function(series) {
                    series.segments.each(function(segment) {
                        segment.setState("default");
                    })
                    series.bulletsContainer.setState("default");
                });
            }

        }); // end am4core.ready()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="modalContensfromAjax">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```